# SQL query to return history as flat format

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for help with an SQL query to turn a history table into flat file format with up to 5 instances of results on table B. I have only shown 2 instances in the results. For a bonus point can these be sorted by EFF_DATE ascending?!

[image]

My query so far is

```
SELECT a.REFNO, a.M_NAME, b.EFF_DATE, b.VAL
FROM TABLEA a INNER JOIN TABLEB b ON (a.REFNO=b.REFNO)
WHERE a.REFNO = '1'
```

This is fine for returning results once per row, but how do I modify so up to 5 EFF_DATE and VAL instances are repeated on one row. The dates can be any date and ideally would like them sorted ascending left to right. Only those rows on TABLEB where Val > 0 should be included.

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, can you please post the needed result for that input data?

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej, I have reviewed the screenshot post and realise the error of my ways. The desired results are shown at the bottom of the screenshot.

Comment: The output can be even more precise than you requested. If for a REFNO you had more than five effective dates, which ones would you like shown? It is common to want the most recent five dates, shown in ascending order left to right. Gordon has already offered a solution that could be easily adapted for such an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of columns you want in the history, then you can use conditional aggregation or `pivot`.  The challenge is not having a column for the pivot.

You can easily generate one, though, using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT a.REFNO, a.M_NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN b.EFF_DATE END) as EFF_DATE_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN b.VAL END) as VAL_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN b.EFF_DATE END) as EFF_DATE_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN b.VAL END) as VAL_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN b.EFF_DATE END) as EFF_DATE_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN b.VAL END) as VAL_3
FROM TABLEA a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REFNO ORDER BY EFF_DATE) as seqnum
      FROM TABLEB b
     ) b
     ON a.REFNO = b.REFNO
WHERE a.REFNO = '1'
GROUP BY a.REFNO, a.M_NAME;
```

If you don't know the number of columns in the output, then you will need dynamic SQL or to do the formatting at the application layer.